# Vue js v-for v-bind not unique

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I'm trying to create a form where I have a select list (fetched from API) and user can add items into a seperate array from this list. New array is also rendered via v-for and uses v-model to edit some additional data.

For example I have a list of goods/services defined beforehand which will be rendered into select option block. Now user can select one of these products and add them to a invoice. After adding (pushed to a new array), user must be able to make some additional changes.

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selectedServiceId">
    <option v-for="service in services" :value="service._id">{{service.name}}</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="addService">Add</button>
```

add service method:

```
addService() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.services.length; i++) {
      if (this.services[i]._id == this.selectedServiceId) {
        this.services_goods.push(this.services[i])
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

And now I want to render the list I've pushed into:

```
<ul>
          <li v-for="(item, key) in services_goods">
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <label for="itemPrice">Price €
              <input id="itemPrice" v-model="item.price">
            </label>
            <label for="itemQty">Quantity
              <input type="number" min="1" id="itemQty" v-model="item.quantity">
            </label>
            <div>
              <button type="button" v-on:click="removeService(item._id)">X</button>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

everything is fine up until I add the same item twice and try to modify the price for one of them - it changes price for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it changes the price for both is that they are the same object. When you insert an object into an array, the value in the array is a reference to the object. You have two references to the same object.

Each object you insert into the array should be newly created, with contents copied from the selected item.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedServiceId: null,
    services: [{
        _id: 1,
        price: 1,
        quantity: 1,
        name: 'First'
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        price: 2,
        quantity: 2,
        name: 'Second'
      }
    ],
    services_goods: []
  },
  methods: {
    addService() {
      const foundGood = this.services.find((s) => s._id == this.selectedServiceId);

      // Object.assign copies an object's contents
      this.services_goods.push(Object.assign({}, foundGood));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select class="form-control" v-model="selectedServiceId">
    <option v-for="service in services" :value="service._id">{{service.name}}</option>
</select>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="addService">Add</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, key) in services_goods">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      <label for="itemPrice">Price €
              <input id="itemPrice" v-model="item.price">
            </label>
      <label for="itemQty">Quantity
              <input type="number" min="1" id="itemQty" v-model="item.quantity">
            </label>
      <div>
        <button type="button" v-on:click="removeService(item._id)">X</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```